# Parse snapshot to model - FirebaseUI

Tags: swift, firebase

I am currently moving from Android dev to Swift dev with Firebase.

In Android, it was very easy to parse a snapshot retrieved by Firebase to an object (e.g. dataSnapshot.getvalue(EventModel.class))

How can we achieve the same in Swift? It seems that there is no such functionality. I am using Firebase-ui to retrieve objects for a list, there is a parameter "modelClass", but there is no information on how to define that class.

How do we have to define the following objects:

- EventModel:

  - name : string
  - description : string
  - messages: MessageModel
- MessageModel:

  - author: string
  - content: string

Is there a way to easily define this and parse the snapshot in Swift? Or do we have to use custom functions/classes like ObjectWrapper?

Kind regards,

Henry

Answer (score 4):

Author of FirebaseUI here, good question!

The short answer is that the Objective-C client for Firebase has no similar functionality for the Android/Java `snapshot.getValue(Object.class)`. This is due to several reasons but essentially Java has several things that Objective-C doesn't have (type annotations and generics being the two relevant ones in this case) that prevent us from doing this easily in the client. Typically, people end up building/using a JSON <--> Object mapper (which I assume ObjectWrapper is) given that Objective-C doesn't provide this functionality out of the box.

The longer answer is that doing this is *sort of* possible by using the Objective-C runtime and using reflection to transform the dictionary received into a model object. I hacked together a `modelClass` implementation that's semi-undocumented in FirebaseUI, as it only works in a limited set of circumstances. See below for my quick pass at documentation :)

The current feature simply creates an instance of the class then populates the fields directly from the dictionary provided from `snapshot.value` (see implementation [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/Implementation/FirebaseTableViewDataSource.m#L212-L220)). This means that the properties must exactly match the keys in Firebase. **This also means that it needs to receive a Dictionary back from Firebase--it won't automatically convert Strings, Numbers, Booleans, or Arrays.** It also means that nested objects are unlikely to work, given that Objective-C doesn't have generics (at least not mainstream Obj-C, yet). Specifically, we currently only support single level Javascript objects with values that are primitive types.

If you have a JSON object in Firebase like:

```
{
  message: {
    name: String,
    text: String
  }
}
```

Your Objective-C (or Swift) class would look like:

```
// Obj-C
@interface MyMessageClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *text;

@end

// Swift
class MyMessageClass {

  let name: String!
  let text: String!

}
```

You can then use the `modelClass:(Class)class` property passing in either `[MyModelClass class]` or `MyModelClass.self` in the constructors. Take a look at [ViewController.m](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/examples/FirebaseUIChat/FirebaseUIChat/ViewController.m#L25-L58) and [Message.h](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/examples/FirebaseUIChat/FirebaseUIChat/Message.h) for a simple implementation of how to use this feature.

I'm still testing how well I can make a more robust version that could be merged into the client library (it might look like `-valueAsObject:(Class)class` so you can do something like `MyClass *customClass = [snapshot valueAsObject:[MyClass class]];`) No word on if that's even really possible, or if it ever sees the light of day.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated information :) It would indeed be great if there was more documentation on this in Firebase (-UI), as in Android, it was a very useful function! Working with  models is great, as you can remain consistent in the code, and easily change data. Even showing information on which is the best method to build a custom JSON <-> Object wrapper (with nested objects) would be great!

Comment: Moreover, as a side comment, is it possible to pass a query in the FirebaseTableViewDatasource? Would be useful to order data..

Comment: You can pass in a Firebase Reference or a Firebase Query (FQuery) to a datasource for filtering. We're also working on support for better client side filtering (sorting, predicates, etc.) and [have some PR's out for review](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/pull/12) (mostly pending my schedule).

Comment: Okok, but it seems impossible to pass a FQuery in FirebaseTableViewDataSource. Do you have an example of code in swift? Thanks

Comment: So this looks like an issue with Swift's handling of subtypes... Obj-C is totally fine with you passing an `FQuery` into a place with a `Firebase` ref (`Firebase` is a subclass of `FQuery`). Realistically we should be using `__kindof FQuery *` which *in theory* should solve the problem (though it doesn't apparently work in other places. What we likely have to do is provide second sets of constructors that use `-initWithQuery:...`. for Swift.

Comment: I've created [an issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/17) on the GitHub repo. PR's welcome, if you'd like to contribute :) Should be pretty straightforward to add new methods to `FirebaseDataSource`, `FirebaseTableViewDataSource`, and `FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource`

Comment: @user3900157 FWIW, this is slated to be fixed in v0.3.1 of FirebaseUI (ideally we can cut it before Thanksgiving so you can play with it over the holidays)

Comment: This should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [library](https://github.com/Appyx/SnapshotParser) with similar functionality as the android version.
It's a generic parser which allows you to easily convert a snapshot into a swift object(or a list).

For your question the following code would do the job:

```
func main(){
    let model=SnapshotParser().parse(snap: Snapshot, type: EventModel.self)
}

class EventModel: ParsableObject {
    var name:String?=nil
    var description:String?=nil
    var messages:[MessageModel]?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "name", field: &name)
        binder.bindField(name: "description", field: &description)
        binder.bindList(name: "messages", list: &messages)
    }
}
class MessageModel: ParsableSnapshot {
    var id: String?
    var author:String?=nil
    var content:String?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "id", field: &id)
        binder.bindField(name: "author", field: &author)
        binder.bindField(name: "content", field: &content)
    }
}
```

The json would be something like:

```
    "eventModel":{
        "name":"bob",
        "description":"this is bob",
        "messages":{
            "id1":{
                "author":"alice",
                "content":"long text"
            },
            "id2":{
                "author":"alice",
                "content":"long text"
            }
        }
    }
```